# Sas macro conditional join using %if %then %else

Tags: join, sas, conditional-statements, sas-macro

I am trying to join two tables, weight 1 and weight2.
I want to join these two tables on ID1=ID2 first.
if there is a missing ID, I will join on DOB1=DOB2.
I want the program to compare each row in the table.
but sas saw the first ID is missing in weight2 table, then it completely switch to the else statement, and use DOB1=DOB2 to join.

My Ideal result is to have four rows joined. but now sas only gives me three rows.

```
data weight1;    

   input ID1 $ Week1 DOB1; 

   datalines;            
1111 195  101
2222 220  102
3333 173  103
4444 135  104
;                           

proc print data=weight1;    
run; 

data weight2;    
  infile datalines missover;  
   input ID2 $ Week2 DOB2; 

   datalines;            
     195  101
2222 220  102
3333 173  103
4444 135  104
;                           

proc print data=weight2;    
run;  

options mlogic symbolgen mprint; 
%macro test ;
proc sql;
create table final as 
select a.ID1, a.DOB1, b.ID2,b.DOB2

from weight1 a
%if %sysfunc(exist(b.ID2)) %then 
inner join weight2 b 
on a.ID1 = b.ID2;
%else 
/*%if %sysfunc(not exist(b.IDnumber))*/
inner join weight2 b
on a.DOB1 = b.DOB2
;
;
quit;
%mend test;

%test
```

Sas log:

```
LOGIC(TEST):  Beginning execution.
MPRINT(TEST):   proc sql;
MLOGIC(TEST):  %IF condition %sysfunc(exist(b.ID2)) is FALSE
MPRINT(TEST):   create table final as select a.ID1, a.DOB1, b.ID2,b.DOB2 from weight1 a inner join weight2 b on a.DOB1 = b.DOB2 ;
NOTE: Table WORK.FINAL created, with 3 rows and 4 columns.
```

this is my ideal result

```
ID1    DOB1 ID2    DOB2
1111    101         101
2222    102 2222    102
3333    103 3333    103
4444    104 4444    104
```

Comment: Why are you testing whether there is a dataset named `ID2` in a library pointed to by the libref `B`? Aren't your datasets named WEIGHT1, WEIGHT2, etc?

Comment: Have you examined the data and print out ? The `weight2` step's first `dataline` should use dot (`.`) place holder for missing id2 value.

Comment: Thanks Richard for bringing this up. I will add a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` expression can be used as join criteria.

Do not use macro.  Your use of `%sysfunc(exist` is just wrong, the `exist` function checks for the existence of a data set, and `%sysfunc` is performed pre source code compilation time, not at SQL execution time.

Use a case expression to evaluate the pre-conditions for your equality check.

Example:

```
data weight1;    

   input ID1 $ Week1 DOB1; 

   datalines;            
1111 195  101
2222 220  102
3333 173  103
4444 135  104
;                           

data weight2;    
  infile datalines missover;  
   input ID2 $ Week2 DOB2; 

   datalines;            
.    195  101
2222 220  102
3333 173  103
4444 135  104
;                           

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select a.ID1, a.DOB1, b.ID2,b.DOB2
  from weight1 a
  join weight2 b
    on case 
         when (a.id1 is not missing and b.id2 is not missing) then a.id1=b.id2
         when (a.dob1 is not missing and b.dob2 is not missing) then a.dob1=b.dob2
         else 0
       end
  ;
```

NOTE: The case of real data where you have more than one row in each table with missing id and the same date of birth will cause a multiplicative row count effect in the result table.  Such as this sample data:

```
1111 195  101
2222 220  102
3333 173  103
4444 135  104
.    145  105 ***
.    175  105 ***
```

and

```
.    195  101
2222 220  102
3333 173  103
4444 135  104
.    155  105 ***
.    166  105 ***
```

4 = 2 x 2 result rows from the starred data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! This is the answer!!

Comment: "the exist function checks for the existence of a data set, and %sysfunc is performed pre source code compilation time, not at SQL execution time." Exactly the reason why there is error.  The case when statement works like gold.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Kailey, be sure to mark answers to your questions, and up vote useful answers you find regarding any question you search out.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The other thing is that the performance for this case when method is not very good. since my dataset is really big (each table contain around 400k rows), the query has been running for 3 hours now. Do you know the method to improve the performance?

Comment: What are the actual columns names, types and sizes ?  The when join criteria force an outer join to occur so there are 400k x 400k operations going on, and also many 'replicates' can occur in the result set if the id values are not unique (again there is a multiplicative effective), which can lead to a lot of 'Output' time writing the result -- the UNION approach shown by @RuneS could be faster, especially if the data sets have indices for id, and dob, and the id's are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

If you trusted the join on DOBs as much as the one on IDs, you could simply do `on a.ID1 = b.ID2 or a.DOB1 = b.DOB2`. But I assume the DOB-match could give some wrong results when IDs aren't missing.

You could first select all rows where you have both sets of IDs, and then select all rows where DOBs match and either ID is missing. Use a `union`to get them into the same table. I can't test my code right now, but something like this:

```
proc sql;
create table final as 
select a.ID1, a.DOB1, b.ID2,b.DOB2
from weight1(where=(not missing(ID1)) a 
 inner join weight2(where=(not missing(ID2)) b 
 on a.ID1 = b.ID2
union
select a.ID1, a.DOB1, b.ID2,b.DOB2
from weight1 a 
 inner join weight2 b 
 on a.DOB1 = b.DOB2 and (missing(ID1) or missing(ID2))
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason why I can’t join on DOB only is because some times there is missing data in the DOB column as well.

Comment: Missing values doesn't give any problems, in the sense that `final` wont have any wrongly matched rows (missing values will give a smaller data set, if both DOB and ID is missing). If all values are correct if non-missing, you could simply use the `or`-approach. 

Otherwise, if DOB is potentially erronous or non-unique, so the ID-match must be prioritized, the `union` approach should work.